# Does Ethereum Wallet Really Work?

Tags: mining, wallets

I'm a newb at Ethereum Wallet for sure, but as best I can tell it's useless. I  can create accounts ok, but that's it. I originally sync'd with the blockchain the first time, but since then I'm always out of sync by about 600K blocks no matter how many peers are connected. Mining on testnet for hours produces nothing. I can't create a wallet because I need ether to pay for the contract, and geth is always near or at the top of my memory usage among processes despite producing nothing. I'm eager to use this platform and get in the game, but this thing is basically wallpaper for me. Does anyone have suggestions?

Maybe this will help. I typed the following at my command line: get --testnet console

and got:

```
C:\Users\I'mBIG\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum Wallet\binaries\Geth\unpacked>geth --testnet console
I0327 20:18:01.525140 node/config.go:445] Failed to start Ledger hub, disabling: libusb: not found [code -5]
I0327 20:18:01.526141 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to C:\Users\I'mBIG\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\testnet\geth\chaindata
I0327 20:18:01.683689 ethdb/database.go:176] closed db:C:\Users\I'mBIG\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\testnet\geth\chaindata
I0327 20:18:01.686694 node/node.go:176] instance: Geth/v1.5.9-stable/windows/go1.7.4
I0327 20:18:01.686694 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to C:\Users\I'mBIG\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\testnet\geth\chaindata
I0327 20:18:01.766701 core/genesis.go:95] Genesis block already in chain. Writing canonical number
I0327 20:18:01.766701 eth/backend.go:276] Successfully wrote custom genesis block: 41941023680923e0fe4d74a34bdac8141f2540e3ae90623718e47d66d1ca4a2d
I0327 20:18:01.768702 eth/backend.go:187] Protocol Versions: [63 62], Network Id: 3
I0327 20:18:01.768702 eth/backend.go:215] Chain config: {ChainID: 3 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: true EIP150: 0 EIP155: 10 EIP158: 10}
I0327 20:18:01.771704 core/blockchain.go:219] Last header: #643824 [338826d9…] TD=399626631294546
I0327 20:18:01.771704 core/blockchain.go:220] Last block: #643824 [338826d9…] TD=399626631294546
I0327 20:18:01.771704 core/blockchain.go:221] Fast block: #643824 [338826d9…] TD=399626631294546
I0327 20:18:01.773706 p2p/server.go:340] Starting Server
I0327 20:18:03.969550 p2p/nat/nat.go:111] mapped network port udp:30303 -> 30303 (ethereum discovery) using UPNP IGDv2-IP1
I0327 20:18:04.018693 p2p/discover/udp.go:227] Listening, enode://a5faacd06a381de0895a7cae118e1cc5113a92618d35b39829198f146e73c259a0833a3b4dfcd1fdad82396d3a0b1aed743b0e79b4885a063942370fec750de7@198.72.238.217:30303
I0327 20:18:04.019668 p2p/server.go:608] Listening on [::]:30303
I0327 20:18:04.026672 node/node.go:341] IPC endpoint opened: \\.\pipe\geth.ipc
I0327 20:18:04.070213 p2p/nat/nat.go:111] mapped network port tcp:30303 -> 30303 (ethereum p2p) using UPNP IGDv2-IP1
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.5.9-stable/windows/go1.7.4
coinbase: 0x127829fcd841134d9b949edf0feb4646f0cdd4e1
at block: 643824 (Mon, 27 Mar 2017 20:12:59 PDT)
 datadir: C:\Users\I'mBIG\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\testnet
 modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want to interact with Dapps? Do you want to store other ERC-20 tokens?

Comment: Looking to start writing contracts

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange!  Please check this http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask because this question may get removed if flagged.

Answer (score 1):

If you want work with contracts.

Rather connecting to testnet, create the private blockchain then deploy your contract.

If you start mining in the private network you will get ethers immediately to your account.

https://souptacular.gitbooks.io/ethereum-tutorials-and-tips-by-hudson/content/private-chain.html

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Setting-up-private-network-or-local-cluster

Comment: This looks promising. Once I get the private network running, can I no longer use Mist? I have to run all my code and contracts through a command line?